# How to make joins in my criteria in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, stored-procedures

I have three tables:

**1.FT_ViewItemMovement **

```
StoreID    ItemLookupCode   QTY
-------------------------------
1001       11121111         222
1001       11121111         1
1201       11121111         333
1201       11121111         2
```

**2.Item**

```
ItemLookupCode   ID
------------------------
11121111         111
```

**3.ItemDynamic**

```
ItemID    StoreID    SnapShotQuantity
-------------------------------------
111       1201          50

111       1001          25

111       5000          75
111       7777          100
```

**Expecting Result**

```
ItemID    StoreID    QTY    SnapShotQuantity   
-------------------------------------
111       1201       335    50
111       1001       223    25
111       5000        0     75
111       7777        0     100
```

I Tried this following Query, But I didn't get

```
SELECT 
    ViewItemMovement.ItemLookupCode,
    ViewItemMovement.StoreID,

    Sum(ViewItemMovement.Quantity) Quantity,
    ItemDynamic.SnapShotQuantity SanpShotQuantity       

FROM 
    FT_ViewItemMovement ViewItemMovement 
    left join Item with(NoLock) on Item.ItemLookupCode = ViewItemMovement.ItemLookupCode 
    left join ItemDynamic with(NoLock) on ItemDynamic.ItemID = Item.ID and ItemDynamic.StoreID = ViewItemMovement.StoreID

WHERE brand = 'PEPSI'
Group By  
    ViewItemMovement.ItemLookupCode,
    ViewItemMovement.StoreID,
    ViewItemMovement.ItemDescription,
    ViewItemMovement.Brand,
    Item.Cost,
    ItemDynamic.SnapShotQuantity
```

> first I want to summarise the quanity of `FT_ViewItemMovement.Qty` by **StoreID and ItemLookupCode** and then if it matches the same itemID with **ItemDynamic** it has to bring `SnapShotQuanity`
>
> If there is no `FT_ViewItemMovement.Qty`, then show `FT_ViewItemMovement.Qty = 0` as Expecting output

Answer (score 0):

Your `GROUP BY` clause looks too complicated.  I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT vim.ItemLookupCode, vim.StoreID,
       COALESCE(Sum(vim.Quantity), 0) as Quantity,
       id.SnapShotQuantity as SanpShotQuantity       
FROM FT_ViewItemMovement vim LEFT JOIN
     Item i 
     ON i.ItemLookupCode = vim.ItemLookupCode LEFT JOIN
     ItemDynamic id
     ON id.ItemID = i.ID and id.StoreID = vim.StoreID
WHERE vim.brand = 'PEPSI'
GROUP BY vim.ItemLookupCode, vim.StoreID,
      id.SnapShotQuantity;
```

Your `WHERE` clause references `brand`.  I have no idea where that comes from based on your question.

Comment: it is not showing all StoreID Snapshot from `ItemDynamic.StoreID`

Comment: In **ItemDynamic** One Item have 5 storeID with `SnapShotQuantity`.  But in `FT_ViewItemMovement ` it has only 2 storeid with that same item. So I want to display all the storeid's Itemlookupcode

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your query by looking at what you need, which is two `SUM`'s and a `GROUP BY` containing the other selections, while using `StoreID` from `FT_ViewItemMovement` to allow the `SUM(v.QTY)` to work.

```
SELECT id.ItemID, v.StoreID, SUM(v.QTY), SUM(id.SnapShotQuantity)
FROM FT_ViewItemMovement v
INNER JOIN Item i ON v.ItemLookupCode = i.ItemLookupCode
INNER JOIN ItemDynamic id ON i.ID = id.ItemID
GROUP BY id.ItemID, v.StoreID
```

Answer (score 0):

With your data sample, you must select from ItemDynamic then use join other table.
I hope it will work for you.

```
SELECT 
    ItemDynamic.ItemID,
    ItemDynamic.StoreID,
    SUM(ViewItemMovement.Quantity) AS Quantity,
    MAX(ItemDynamic.SnapShotQuantity) AS SanpShotQuantity
FROM 
    ItemDynamic with(NoLock) 
    left join Item with(NoLock) on Item.ID = ItemDynamic.ItemID 
    left join FT_ViewItemMovement ViewItemMovement on ViewItemMovement.ItemLookupCode = Item.ItemLookupCode and ViewItemMovement.StoreID = ItemDynamic.StoreID

Group By  
    ItemDynamic.ItemID,
    ItemDynamic.StoreID
```

Comment: It's not bringing all storeid from ItemDynamic